# Getting NFS RDMA to work in RHEL 8

Tags: rhel, nfsv4

I'm using RHEL 8.7 on both the client and the server, a clean install from rhel-8.7-x86_64-dvd.iso.

The `/etc/nfs.conf` and `/etc/nfsmount.conf` files are unmodified.

On the nfsserver

```
mkdir /data
chmod /data
systemctl disable firewalld --now
```

The contents of `/etc/exports`:

```
/data   *(rw,async,no_root_squash)
```

```
# exportfs -s
/data  *(async,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

On the nfs client:

```
# mkdir /data
# mount 192.168.1.1:/data /data
# mount | grep data

192.168.1.1:/data on /data type nfs4
(rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.2,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1)
```

**How can  I get RDMA to work?**

Am I correct in that I should be seeing `proto=rdma` in the mount on the client side, rather than `proto=tcp`?  If not, how do I verify RDMA is in effect?`

Comment: Hello the procedure for RHEL 7.9 is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684194/infiniband-rhel7-nfs-rdma-setup-help, should be the same on RHEL 8.7 except if your Network cards doesn't support it.

Comment: haha, thanks for reminding me

Comment: that explains the deja vu feeling I was having, typing this question for rhel8

Answer (score 2):

for those interest, in RHEL 8.7 this is the deal

- clean install from rhel-8.7-x86_64-dvd.iso
- On the NFS Server side you must edit `/etc/nfs.conf` and uncomment `rdma=n` and set that to `rdma=y`.  This does not need to be done on the nfs client side.

  - this is at the bottom of the `[nfsd]` block.
  - you don't need to modify anything else in this file, everything else will be commented out.
- on the nfs client, you must do `mount -o rdma <server>:/<folder>  <folder>` in order to see `proto=rdma` when validating your `mount` otherwise it will show as *proto=tcp*.  You do not need to do `mount -o rdma,port=20049`.
- on both the server side and client side, be sure in `/etc/rdma/modulefiles/rdma.conf` does not have `xprtrdma` {NFS over RDMA client support} nor `svcrdma` {NFS over RDMA server support} commented out.  By default they should not be.

  - By default only `rds_rdma` is commented out, this is not required to be uncommented to get nfs `proto=rdma` to happen.  Whether `rds_rdma` is beneficial or not I do not know at this point in time.

Comment: rdma=y was the missing part from official Red Hat documentation.

Comment: **note:** `/proc/fs/nfsd/portlist` must contain `rdma <rdma-port>.  if not then a client `mount -o rdma` will never work.  After boot in RHEL 8.8 this does not happen, one must manually do a `service nfs-server restart` to see the entry in the `portlist` file.

Comment: **note:** there's also seems to be an undocumented choice in `/etc/nfs.conf` in that one would logically think either `rdma=n` or `rdma=y`.  You need to do **rdma=nfsrdma** there.